# Acrobat cannot read .FDF written with Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel, acrobat, fdf

I exported a PDF with form fields in FDF and wrote a sub to output another FDF verbatim, with cell values for the form field values. If I edit the FDF in a text editor and change the values, Acrobat can read the file just fine, but the file output with VBA throws an error:

> Adobe could not open *whatever*.fdf because it is either not a supported file type or because the file has been damaged

I've tried two different types of line breaks, I've tried a similar sub with xfdf formatting which is slightly different with the same results.

```
Sub something()

Dim sht As Worksheet
Set sht = Sheets("owssvr")

Dim lastrow As Integer
lastrow = sht.Cells(sht.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim Fileout As Object

Dim x As Integer
For x = 2 To lastrow
    Set Fileout = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\Users\blabla\" & x & ".fdf", True, True)
                Fileout.Write "%FDF-1.2" & vbCrLf & _
                "%âãÏÓ" & vbCrLf & _
                "1 0 obj" & vbCrLf & _
                "<</FDF<</F(MyDocument.pdf)/Fields[<</T(Adobe Form Field)/V(" & sht.Range("U" & x) & ")>>]/ID[<4ED54800AC4A3D41ABE4F4C7B12A3D23><609E705B7532334B8F914CFF4C09F2A0>]/UF(MyDocument.pdf)>>/Type/Catalog>>" & vbCrLf & _
                "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
                "trailer" & vbCrLf & _
                "<</Root 1 0 R>>" & vbCrLf & _
                "%%EOF" & vbCrLf
Fileout.Close

Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: I suspect an encoding issue. Consider using the `StrConv` function to ensure proper encoding (`vbUnicode`?)

Comment: good callout but no avail with vbunicode

Comment: `"%âãÏÓ"` is ANSI-encoded string literal - if that's meant to be unicode, `vbUnicode`-encoding `"%âãÏÓ"` will probably not magically turn it into the unicode equivalent; you may need to use it in combination with `ChrW` to issue *actual* unicode characters.

Comment: I'm afraid I've never used Chr or Chrw, could you give me an example how to get started with that?

Comment: `Debug.Print Chr(65)` prints ASCII 65, an uppercase `A`. `ChrW(1024)` outputs whatever the unicode character is at position 1024; note that the VBE is using ANSI encoding, so you can't use `Debug.Print` to output unicode (everything will show up as `?`). [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/613dxh46(v=vs.90).aspx) has docs for the VB.NET equivalent functions (VBA functions' documentation is pretty hard to find off Google).

Comment: Found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264465.aspx) on `Chr`; note that VBA for Mac doesn't support unicode strings (wtf?!)

Comment: So I'm a little dense..so instead of for example "%âãÏÓ" ,  should I try: ChrW(226) & ChrW(37) &  ChrW(227) &  ChrW(207) &  ChrW(211)

Comment: I'd think `"%âãÏÓ"` is just an ANSI/ASCII representation of the actual characters you want to write. Try viewing an unaltered file in Notepad++ to get the real Unicode characters.  ...encoding is a PITA in VBA, I feel your pain - if you can do this in .net instead, do it.

Comment: I just don't get it. If I look at the files side by side in NP++, they look identical. I can edit the original export and it will still work. Hell if I copy and paste from the original to a new file, it works. Something VBA is writing is rendering it useless. I suppose I could try a long string replace loop on the original but I haven't really done that before so it might take me some time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As much as I want to leave this open in hopes somebody figures out WHY VBA is screwing up the unicode, my problem can be solved without invoking fso at all and just using FreeFile and string replace on an original FDF

```
Sub blabla()

Dim objAcroApp As Acrobat.AcroApp
Dim objAcroAVDoc As Acrobat.AcroAVDoc
Dim objAcroPDDoc As Acrobat.AcroPDDoc
Dim jsObj As Object
Dim boResult As Boolean
Dim oldPDF As String
Dim NewFilePath As String

    Dim sTemp As String
    Dim iFileNum As Integer
    Dim oldFDF As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set sht = Sheets("owssvr")

    With sht
        lastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    For i = 2 To lastRow

    oldPDF = "\mydoc.pdf"
    oldFDF = "\mydoc_data.fdf"
    newPDF = "\" & i & ".pdf"

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    Open oldFDF For Input As iFileNum

    Do Until EOF(iFileNum)
    Line Input #iFileNum, sBuf
    sTemp = sTemp & vbCrLf
    Loop
    Close iFileNum

    sTemp = Replace(sTemp, "<</T(some form field)/V( )>>", "<</T(some form field)/V(" & sht.Range("E" & i) & ")>>")

    iFileNum = FreeFile
    oldFDF = "\" & i & ".fdf"
    Open oldFDF For Output As iFileNum

    Print #iFileNum, sTemp

    Close iFileNum

            Set objAcroApp = CreateObject("AcroExch.App")
            Set objAcroAVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
            boResult = objAcroAVDoc.Open(oldPDF, "")
            Set objAcroPDDoc = objAcroAVDoc.GetPDDoc
            Set jsObj = objAcroPDDoc.GetJSObject
            jsObj.ImportAnFDF oldFDF
            jsObj.SaveAs newPDF
            boResult = objAcroAVDoc.Close(True)
            boResult = objAcroApp.Exit

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: Now I really wonder that you use FDF to fill the forms at all. With Acrobat you can fill it direct using JSObject.

Comment: *facepalm* wow I didn't realize that. I'll look through the API manual again and see what I'd have to do

Answer (score 1):

Simply **leave out** the line: "%âãÏÓ" & vbCrLf & _". /ID and /UF keys not really needed.

Something like this should work:

```
Fileout.Write "%FDF-1.2" & vbCrLf & _
            "1 0 obj<</FDF<<" & vbCrLf & _
            "/F(MyDocument.pdf)" & vbCrLf & _
            "/Fields" & vbCrLf & _
            "[<</T(Adobe Form Field)/V(xyValue)>>]" & vbCrLf & _            
            ">>>>" & vbCrLf & _
            "endobj" & vbCrLf & _
            "trailer" & vbCrLf & _
            "<</Root 1 0 R>>" & vbCrLf & _
            "%%EOF" & vbCrLf
```

Comment: same error unfortunately. I just don't get it. If I look at the files side by side in NP++, they look identical. I can edit the original export and it will still work. Hell if I copy and paste from the original to a new file, it works. Something VBA is writing is rendering it useless. I suppose I could try a long string replace loop on the original but I haven't really done that before so it might take me some time.

Comment: It's a little bit late in Germany. If you don't get it, I'll spent you tomorrow a vbs.

Answer (score 1):

You will find that in the Acrobat IAC documentation. Here a quick vbs(vba) example. Where you need only 2 lines from that: jso.getField and f.value =... Good luck.

```
  '//-> Set a value for a form field via JSO
  '//-> Settings
FileNm = "d:\TestInput.pdf"
FieldNm= "Input1"
FieldValue= "50"
  '//-> let's start
Set App = CreateObject("Acroexch.app")
app.show
Set AVDoc = CreateObject("AcroExch.AVDoc")
    '//-> open the file and put the value in
If AVDoc.Open(FileNM,"") Then
    Set PDDoc = AVDoc.GetPDDoc()
    Set jso = PDDoc.GetJSObject
  '//-> Get the field and put a value in
    set f = jso.getField(FieldNm)
    f.value = FieldValue
end if
```